# Resampling shifted intervals with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the following time series (illustration purposes):

```
From                | Till                | Precipitation
2022-01-01 06:00:00 | 2022-01-02 06:00:00 | 0.5
2022-01-02 06:00:00 | 2022-01-03 06:00:00 | 1.2
2022-01-03 06:00:00 | 2022-01-04 06:00:00 | 0.0
2022-01-04 06:00:00 | 2022-01-05 06:00:00 | 1.3
2022-01-05 06:00:00 | 2022-01-06 06:00:00 | 9.8
2022-01-06 06:00:00 | 2022-01-07 06:00:00 | 0.1
```

I'd like to estimate the daily precipitation between `2022-01-02 00:00:00` and `2022-01-06 00:00:00`. We can assume that the rate of precipitation is constant for each given interval in the table.

Doing manually I'd assume something like

```
2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 0.25 * 0.5 + 0.75 * 1.2
```

**Note**: the real-world data will most likely look much less regular, somewhat like the following (missing intervals can be assumed to be 0.0):

```
From                | Till                | Precipitation
2022-01-01 05:45:12 | 2022-01-02 02:11:20 | 0.8
2022-01-03 02:01:59 | 2022-01-04 12:01:00 | 5.4
2022-01-04 06:00:00 | 2022-01-05 06:00:00 | 1.3
2022-01-05 07:10:00 | 2022-01-06 07:10:00 | 9.2
2022-01-06 02:54:00 | 2022-01-07 02:53:59 | 0.1
```

1. Maybe there's a library with a general and efficient solution?
2. If there's no such library, how do I compute the resampled time series in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

just calculate the period overlaps ... I think this will be plenty fast

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def create_test_data():
    # just a helper to construct a test dataframe
    from_dates = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01 06:00:00', freq='D', periods=6)
    till_dates = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-02 06:00:00', freq='D', periods=6)
    precip_amounts = [0.5, 1.2, 1, 2, 3, 0.5]
    return pd.DataFrame({'From': from_dates, 'Till': till_dates, 'Precip': precip_amounts})


def get_between(df, start_datetime, end_datetime):
    # all the entries that end (Till) after start_time
    # and start(From) before the end
    mask1 = df['Till'] > start_datetime
    mask2 = df['From'] < end_datetime
    return df[mask1 & mask2]


def get_ratio_values(df, start_datetime, end_datetime, debug=True):
    # get the ratios of the period windows
    df2 = get_between(df, start_datetime, end_datetime)  # get only the rows of interest
    precip_values = df['Precip']
    # get overlap from the end time of row to start of our period of interest
    overlap_period1 = df2['Till'] - start
    # get overlap from end of our period of interest and the start time of row
    overlap_period2 = end - df2['From']
    # get the "best" overlap for each row
    best_overlap = np.minimum(overlap_period1, overlap_period2)
    # get the period of each duration
    window_durations = df2['Till'] - df2['From']
    # calculate the ratios of overlap (cannot be greater than 1)
    ratios = np.minimum(1.0, best_overlap / window_durations)
    # calculate the value * the ratio
    ratio_values = ratios * precip_values
    if debug:
        # just some prints for verification
        print("Ratio * value = result")
        print("----------------------")
        print("\n".join(f"{x:0.3f} * {y:0.2f} = {z}" for x, y, z in zip(ratios, df['Precip'], ratio_values)))
        print("----------------------")
    return ratio_values


start = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-02 00:00:00')
end = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-04 00:00:00')
ratio_vals = get_ratio_values(create_test_data(), start, end)
total_precip = ratio_vals.sum()
print("SUM RESULT   =", total_precip)
```

you could also just calculate for the first and last entry since anything in the middle will be 1 always (which is probably both simpler and faster)

```
def get_ratio_values(df, start_datetime, end_datetime, debug=True):
    # get the ratios of the period windows
    df2 = get_between(df, start_datetime, end_datetime)  # get only the rows of interest
    precip_values = df['Precip']
    # overlap with first row and duration of first row
    overlap_start = df2[0]['Till'] - start
    duration_start = df2[0]['Till'] - df2[0]['From']

    # overlap with last row and duration of last row
    overlap_end = end - df2[-1]['From']
    duration_start = df2[-1]['Till'] - df2[-1]['From']

    ratios = [1]* len(df2)
    ratios[0] = overlap_start/duration_start
    ratios[-1] = overlap_end/duration_end

    return ratios * precip_values
```